# Interpreting an EMC radiated emission test result

Tags: electromagnetism, emc, emc-filtering

I am new to EMC. Our team performed an EMC radiated emission test below is the image of the test result.

I am struggling to understand the result. My collegue told me that the 16 MHz clock frequency is easily visible, and the product's radiation seems to cross power lines and pass through several connections from the main PCB. I am not able to see any 16 MHz in the waveform. It is starting from 30 MHz. I have few questions.

From where they got 16 MHz?

What you mean by peak vertical and peak horizontal?

What you mean by average vertical and horizontal?

Peak or average value, which one needs to be given high priority?

[image]

Comment: You collagues are right. Just wondering, why are you not discussing with your colleagues about it?

Comment: Look at the peaks at 32MHz, 48MHz and so on. Those are harmonics of 16MHz.

Comment: It would be useful to have photographs of the equipment under test, as set up in the test chamber, to discuss the relevance of polarization.

Comment: Horizontal versus vertical would be the product's orientation towards the antenna. Depending on your product category and this EMC rules, the _quasi-peak_ could be what ultimately determines compliance or not. Check which one yours fall in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are always [harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic), these can be worse in EMC tests.

[image: annotated picture of OP]

I annotated a few, you can see the harmonics of 16 MHz, the 32/48/64/80/96/112/128...

Or your product has USB, because of the 48 MHz.

Did the EMC lab use near field probes to give you hints where the worst offenders were located on the board? Because there are some wider peaks that are probably noise from other switching signals. Eg: fast edges, or dc-dc converters.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful for a beginner like me. In my board USB is present that is used for programming. If you don't mind could you please highlight the Wider peaks

Answer (score 2):

As Peter Smith says, the harmonics of 16MHz are visible. For peaks that aren’t a harmonic of known clock sources on the board you have to go looking. Things like buck converters tend to radiate up around 100MHz.

EMC is a bit of a ‘black art’ - with experience you get to know what might be radiating. There’s also plenty to read on the subject.

For horizontal and vertical - this is the polarization of the antenna connected to the spectrum analyser used for the test. You can deduce what might be radiating based on whether the peak is highest in the vertical or horizontal plane. The pcb tracks are horizontal and an inductor or cable might be vertical.
Peak and average are what they say. The peak is the highest value measured whereas the average is the value averaged over time.
Depending on what standard you are testing to determines which is significant. For CISPR22 it would be quasi peak.
Upon looking at the report closer, it notes that the standard used is CISPR16 and the peak is ‘Q peak’ aka quasi peak.
Another EMC skill is knowing and understanding the various standards.